# how to create a text file and insert error message into it in ADFV2

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

We have a copy activity in ADF and the requirement is to abort the operation on failure,send the mail with error message and log the error information in a text file in blob storage.

Till sending the mail with error message, the task is completed using logic apps.Since skip and log cannot be done in ADF fault tolerance in our case to store the error information in blob storage.Is there a way we can log the error information in a text file in blob storage using ADF when fault tolerance for copy activity is set as 'abort activity on first incompatible row'?

Please let me know if there is any way to log the error information in blob storage when fault tolerance is 'abort activity on first incompatible row'.

Answer (score 0):

vicky,based on the [Fault tolerance document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance#configuration) and options in the ADF UI,there are only 3 options we could pick:

[image]

Only `"Skip and log incompatible rows"` could save the error log into Azure Blob Storage which is configured by us. No any direct way to save the error log into Azure Storage if you have to pick `"abort activity on first incompatible row"`.

So,my workaround is adding a [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) behind the Copy Activity if the Copy Activity Status is Failure,like this:

[image]

I make a error situation on purpose for copy activity and you could view the output of Copy Activity which contains error message:

[image]

Then you could refer this message in the azure function body by `@activity('Copy data1').output`

[image]

Inside the azure function,you could store it into blob storage using sdk code.

---

> can you please share the code for azure function to store the error
>   information inside the blob storage as i dont have much knowledge of
>   c#.

I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=csharp#output---usage) to test c# code for you:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
            [Blob("test/error.txt", FileAccess.ReadWrite)] CloudBlockBlob blob,
            TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;
            await blob.UploadTextAsync(name);
            if (name == null)
            {
                // Get request body
                dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                name = data?.name;
            }
            return name == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

The `name` parameter is the `error message` you need to pass.Then it will be saved into `test/error.txt` path.

Comment: Thanks Jay Gong for the reply.I was able to capture the error using the dynamic content '@{activity('movefile').Error.Message}' and send this in an email as i mentioned in my question above. can you please share the code for azure function to store the error information inside the blob storage as i dont have much knowledge of c#.

Comment: @vicky Sorry vicky, i replied so late. Please see my working sample code for azure function to storing message into blob storage. Thanks.

Comment: Jay Gong,thanks for the code and really appreciate your help.Was busy with something,will check and update you.Thanks again for the reply with code.

Comment: @vicky You are so kind, please deal with the high priority first. Any updates please sync here.